# Espresso scrollTo not working on ScrollView hosting LinearLayout which hosts programmatically generated LinearLayouts

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a ScrollView which hosts a LinearLayout which at run time then then hosts a bunch of LinearLayouts (inside the previous LinearLayout).

I want to run an espresso test which scrolls to a view off screen (further down the scrollview) which gets clicked to take me to the next activity. When running the espresso test, I've tried using ViewActions.scrollTo to get to it, but it just gives me a resource not found exception.

However if I put a breakpoint in before the click part of the test, manually scroll so the view is visible then run the 'click' part of the test, the test runs absolutely fine.

Does anyone know why the scroll to wouldn't work?

I set the LinearLayouts id to their one of the data fields so I know the ID.

Test Code:

```
@Test
public void ensureScoreCorrect() {
    int manUtdView = Math.abs("Man Utd".hashCode());
    String score = getScore();
    Log.d("Hashcode:", " " + Math.abs("Man Utd".hashCode()));

    onView(withId(manUtdView)).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo());
    onView(withId(manUtdView)).perform(click());

    onView(withId(R.id.details_score))
            .check(matches(withText(score)));
}
```

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/all_matches_fragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="90dp">

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. did you get any fix for this?